# input type color with presets doesn't work with chrome beta

Tags: html, color-picker, html-datalist

I have this input type color with presets using datalist.

```
<input type="color" list="presetColors">
<datalist id="presetColors">
  <option value="#ff0000"/>
  <option value="#00ff00"/>
  <option value="#0000ff"/>
</datalist>
```

But, it doesn't work with chrome beta. So, it means the input type color with datalist will not work on the next release of chrome version?

How can we fix this? it shows white when we select any from the datalist.

[image]

Here's the fiddle and visit this page using chrome beta:
https://jsfiddle.net/nuesLq2b/

Comment: This is now broken in official release 107. I see this in my Chrome - Version 107.0.5304.62 (Official Build) (arm64)

Comment: Broken for me too. Selecting a colour from a datalist returns rgba(0,0,0,0) instead of the actual colour.

A workaround I found for now is to use no datalist or set list="" on the input to use the default list.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Hopefully, google will fix this issue.

Comment: They have indeed! As of now, it's fixed in the latest beta. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1378820#c26